# Align consecutive declarations only if they are of the same kind

Tags: c, format, clang-format

Consider this C code snippet:

```c
typedef unsigned char BOOL;
typedef unsigned char uint8;
typedef unsigned short uint16;
typedef unsigned int uint32;

int main() { 
    return 0; 
}
```

Using `clang-format`, I would like to align the `typedef` declarations. To do this, I set the property `AlignConsecutiveDeclarations` to `true` with `AcrossEmptyLines` also to `true`. The problem is that this formats the code in the following way:

```c
typedef unsigned char  BOOL;
typedef unsigned char  uint8;
typedef unsigned short uint16;
typedef unsigned int   uint32;

int                    main() { return 0; }
```

As you can see, the `main` function is also aligned with the `typedef` declarations. As far as I can see, there is no property that detects whether the declarations change "kind" (for lack of a better word). Declarations can only be divided using comments and newlines. Am I missing something? Is there no option to have the code formatted like this?:

```c
typedef unsigned char  BOOL;
typedef unsigned char  uint8;
typedef unsigned short uint16;
typedef unsigned int   uint32;

int main() { return 0; }
```

Comment: `AlignConsecutiveAssignments` has nothing to do with `typedef`. Post your real clang-format config.

Comment: @ultrapoci, When reviewing code, the first thing I do is auto-format it, making the original format moot.  Rather than seek a novel format, consider using a simple auto-format per your _group's_ standards.

Comment: @273K Sorry, I pasted the wrong property. I've edited the question. I've set no other property in the config file except for  `AlignConsecutiveDeclarations ` with `AcrossEmptyLines` true (which I want to be true).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'm not sure I follow. I have no standards for what I'm doing. I just want my code to look like I want it to look using an automatic formatter. I understand standards exist and should be followed, but where I work I wasn't given any rules to follow.

Comment: @ultrapoci "where I work I wasn't given any rules to follow" --> Consider you have a person on your staff that wants to use their own standards instead of industry ones.  Would you want to encourage them to proceed based on their wants and pay them to develop this novel approach or nudge them toward adopting existing industry ones?